# Batch file to keep a file up to date

Tags: batch-file

This sounds simple, but for some reason I'm having trouble!

- Compare \sharelocation\folder\file to c:\folder\file
- If the files are different, replace the local file

So first I need a way to access the NetBIOS share from a batch file, and then I need a way to see if two files are the same.  Does `fc` return an ERRORLEVEL?  Can I use `net` to add a NetBIOS location as a local drive and access it that way?

In a pinch I would be willing to do this in a programming language (I know most of the popular ones) rather than a batch script, but for various reasons I'd prefer to do otherwise.

Comment: Can't you simply copy the file? Why compare to see if it's different, if you're just going to replace it anyway?

Comment: Large files and many users, primarily.  Actually the best thing would be to compare hashes.

Comment: You might find that a tool like [robocopy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Robocopy) is better for doing the compare-and-copy-if-changed. A single command can help you mirror, re-sync, compare modified dates, and much more.

Comment: @ewall: I've used it -- it's very nice.  Can it handle UNC names?

Comment: yes, robocopy can handle UNC names. I believe by default it also only re-copies a given file if the source file's date is newer than the dest (when doing say, a robocopy SRC DST /E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access files on a share using UNC syntax:

```
\\servername\sharename\folder\file
```

This works equally well from a batch file as from a command prompt, no need to map a drive letter.